# WebOptimizer - 404 for images but okay for js/css

Tags: image, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, bundling-and-minification, weboptimizer

I wonder, why is it may going on? All content lies at the same root but js/css are rolled up into bundles and I guess the issue lies somewhere there around the bundles.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @anatol, WebOptimizer is ASP.NET Core middleware for bundling and minification of **CSS and JavaScript** files at runtime.

Comment: hi @Rena, I know. I suspect that it may somehow affect and I need to ensure is it or not. The point is in the screenshot - bundled things are routed well but images are not bundled and give 404 although paths are same

Comment: The separate images also works fine in my project although I use WebOptimizer to bundle the image file. Maybe you need share enough code and project structure of these 404 images.

Comment: @Rena do you provide some custom configs while registering the service itself?

Comment: @Rena do you use tag helpers?

Comment: Hi @anatol, 1. I just follow the github document. 2. not yet. I do not choose to use tag helpers. So maybe more code will be helpful.

Comment: my bad just forgot to include `UseStaticFiles`